# Keep socket alive after node server restart

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io with node for my react-native application.Everything is working fine but the problem comes when a user is connected to the socket and the node server restarts due to any kind of error because of PM2.Therefore the socket is cleared from the socket pool and the user then has to login again to register a new socket for the application to work.Is there any better way than using a setTimeout and checking if the socket does not exists and then creating a new socket automatically?

Comment: The socket.io client will automatically reconnect when the server restarts.  That's a built-in feature of socket.io.  You don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: Nope.It isn't  doing that with me.Is there any property I should hook up my socket conf with to accomplish that behaviour or are you just guessing?

Comment: @Akshay, i don't believe u can do so, when node server is not running, it's just like there is no such server, and of course, no alive socket

Comment: @datdinhquoc I said that the server RESTARTS and socket pool is cleared.So my disconnected sockets have no way to connect again to the socket pool.

Comment: What is this socket pool?  That isn't a feature of socket.io so I don't know what that is.  If you want us to help you make sure your client code is automatically reconnecting socket.io, then you will need to show us your client code that connects and logs in.  You may also need to show us the socket pool code on the server so we can know what you're talking about.